# Does this script get your visitors counted as monthly active users at facebook?

Tags: facebook

If i use only this script would my page visitors at facebook canvas application page get counted as monthly active users ? or do i need something else ? I mean for example i have www.mydomain.com/Facebookapp page and i installed only this script to get my visitors as counted for monthly active users and they are logged in facebook.

thank you.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
      status : true, 
      cookie : true,
      xfbml  : true,  
      channelUrl  : 'http://www.mydomain.com/channel.html', 
      oauth : true
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this script alone won't do anything.  To get people counted as monthly active users, you would at a mininum need a login button that they can click so they can approve your application and then it would start counting them.

Comment: thanks for response. are there any way to do it without clicking button. since the visitors will be from facebook and they will be already logged in facebook ?